# Java Date and Time: How do I make plus() and until() to be each others inverse

Tags: java, java-time, jsr310

Most of the time, these 2 methods are each others inverse:

- `Temporal Temporal.plus(long, TemporalUnit)`
- `long Temporal.until(Temporal, TemporalUnit)`

---

For example starting from 1-JAN:

```
System.out.println("1-JAN plus 1 month: " +
    LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1).plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS));
System.out.println("1-JAN until 1-FEB in months: " +
    LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1).until(LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 1), ChronoUnit.MONTHS));
```

They are each others inverse:

> 1-JAN plus 1 month: 2017-02-01
>      1-JAN until 1-FEB in months: 1 // GOOD

---

However, in this example starting from 31-JAN:

```
System.out.println("31-JAN plus 1 month: " +
    LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 31).plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS));
System.out.println("31-JAN until 28-FEB in months: " +
    LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 31).until(LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 28), ChronoUnit.MONTHS));
```

They are **not** each others inverse:

> 31-JAN plus 1 month: 2017-02-28 // Bad? Should ceil to 1 March?
>       31-JAN until 28-FEB in months: 0 // Or is this bad? Should be 1?

---

How can I make them to be each others inverse?

Comment: Calendar.add.... this will help

Comment: There is less than 1 month between 31-JAN and 28-FEB so how do you consider 0 months bad?

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa can you explain how this will help?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Calendar will *help* me by giving me so much pain that I 'll forget about this problem ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Good point that until is bad, it's probably the plus that is bad. I probably want the plus to ceil instead of to floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only 28 days between those dates so the number of whole months is 0.  However you could use a bit of rounding if you want less than 1 month be be considered a month. e.g.

```
// compare the months after rounding to the next month
LocalDate a = LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 31);
LocalDate b = LocalDate.of(2017, 2, 28);
long months = a.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS)
        .until(b.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS), ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
System.out.println(a + " until " + b + " in months: " + months);
```

prints

```
2017-01-31 until 2017-02-28 in months: 1
```

and

```
// compare the months after rounding to the next month
LocalDate a = LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 31);
LocalDate b = LocalDate.of(2017, 3, 30);
long months = a.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS)
        .until(b.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS), ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
System.out.println(a + " until " + b + " in months: " + months);
```

prints

```
2017-01-31 until 2017-03-30 in months: 2
```

> I probably want the plus to ceil instead of to floor

You might want to treat all months as notionally 30 days depending on your requirements.

Comment: Problem is that I need this to work on all temporal types (not just LocalDates with Month increments). So I wonder if there's a way to do `Temporal.plus(...)` and have it round up (instead of down), as I think that would solve my problem.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet What do you mean by saying "all temporal types"? Do you still speak about a finite number of `Temporal`-implementations? Only about implementations offered by Java-8? Or about ANY such class possibly coming from external libraries?

Comment: I would already be happy with all those offered by Java 8, but I don't look forward to implementing and maintaining every Temporal + ChronoUnit increment combination to round up.

Comment: This approached does work to [implement a Temporal contains() method](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/domain/valuerange/buildin/temporal/TemporalValueRange.java#L94).